# Pass data to "deeper down" components in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

First of all. Sorry about my title, I have been thinking over ten minutes of what I'm going to name my question. But I got nothing, however..

In my app I have three components that basically belongs to each other.

I have:

1. `Doors.js`
2. `DoorsItem.js`
3. `DoorsDetails.js`

So, in `Doors.js` I have this line of code:

```
const items = dataToDisplay.map(item => <DoorsItem item={item} />)
```

And here I'm creating a new element called `DoorsItem` with it's props equal to `item`.

And in my `DoorsItem.js` I have this:

```
const DoorsItem = ({ item }) =>
  <Grid>
    <Row key={item._id} className="show-grid">
      <Col md={12}>

        <ul style={{ marginTop: '10px' }}>
          <li className="info-container">
            <h4 className="title-text-container">{item.address.street}</h4>

            <a
              className="sub-title-text-container"
              style={{
                fontWeight: '300',
                textDecoration: 'underline',
                marginLeft: '500px'
              }}
            >
              Lägg till ny användare
            </a>

            <Link to={`/log/${item._id}`}>
              <p
                className="sub-title-text-container"
                style={{
                  fontWeight: '300',
                  textDecoration: 'underline'
                }}
              >
                Se logg
              </p>
            </Link>
             //etcetc
```

Because I am passing in `item` at the top I’m getting access to all of the different types of props. Like `item.address.street` i.e.

At: `<Link to={`/log/${item._id}`}>` I am linking to a specific path based on an id. And everything works great! However…
When I’m getting deeper into the rabbit hole (`DoorDetails.js`) I got this:

```
const DoorDetails = ({ match }) => {
  // console.log(item) Undefined!!!
  return (
    <div>
      <MainNavbar />
      <Grid>
        <Row className="show-grid">
          <Col md={12}>
            <h1 className="text-center">Sätraängsvägen 12</h1> // Need non-static-address here :p
          </Col>
        </Row>
```

My `item` props is undefined, which I get because I’m passing in `match` here because that’s how react router **V4** works (I based that on the internet hehehe).

#### Question:

So my question is how can I access my `item` props so I can start rendering non-static-data. Like `item.address.street`.

Match:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to change your Link to something like this:

```
 <Link to={{
    pathname: '/some-link',
    state: { item: someItem, blah: someotheritem }
}}/>
```

UPDATED AFTER READING DOCS:

Then in your component add a new prop location:

```
const DoorDetails = ({ match, location }) => {
     const item = location.state.item;
     ...
}
```

Try this out and let me know if it works better.

Comment: Hey! I tried to: `state: { item: item }` in my Link and I also added `const item = match.state.item;` in `Doordetails.js`, nothing happened. :-(

Comment: Did you make sure to change the whole Link prop like the above? Also can you console.log the match and see what is in that variable?

Comment: The Link looks like this atm:

 `<Link to={{pathname: `/log/${item._id}`, state: { item: item }}}></Link>`

And I've updated the question with a photo so you can see in the console what `match` is. Cheers for taking your time!

Comment: Well honestly I think that React router always injects the location prop into the rendered components. Adding the state object to the Link just extends the existing location prop. It is a little harder to see with this example because you aren't building a component class and this.props doesn't exist so you couldn't just console.log(this.props) and see the location object.